# How to fix a PHP website on localhost that shows as a directory and not a website?

Tags: php, webmatrix

I installed **Webmatrix 3** yesterday to create a PHP website. When I try to run the basic PHP page, I only see the directory of the project files
but I want to see the web page directly.

I only have a simple page so far, but this is a major issue. When I run the project file I only get:

```
localhost - /

06/07/2015    14:24        <dir> App_Data
06/07/2015    14:24        <dir> bin
06/07/2015    16:39          187 PHPPage.php
06/07/2015    15:11          659 web.config
```

The only edits to webmatrix have been adding the PHP extension file.

Comment: Just click index.php, in case you don't have that file tell what you have in that directory, write something about your configuration. It's hard to tell anything from what you have just written.

Comment: What I see when I run the project file is ;

Comment: @dagi12                                                                                      localhost - /

06/07/2015    14:24        <dir> App_Data
06/07/2015    14:24        <dir> bin
06/07/2015    16:39          187 PHPPage.php
06/07/2015    15:11          659 web.config

Comment: I think youshould edit your question adding some informations (do not put in comments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename your PHPPage.php to index.php

Only index.php is run automatically instead of showing the dir structure

Comment: This is not the only way to set your default page. You can edit your .htaccess file as mentioned by @whiteclaws or since you are using WebMatrix just edit what your default page is named using the websites settings.

Comment: @Mike Yeah but the most commonly used naming convention used is "index" so that's what I just mentioned here.

Comment: I agree that "index" is the most common, it's just not the **only** way to have a php file run automatically. Which is why I posted here. It might not be feasible for everyone to change the name of the file. It might be simpler to change what files are run automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried creating an .htaccess file in your webroot directory and writing this in?

```
DirectoryIndex <index-webpage>
```

Replace <> by your starting webpage (it is index.php by default)

Another cool tip is to add this to your .htaccess file.

```
Options All -Indexes
```

Now it won't display your files as a web directory when you don't have any DirectoryIndex

Edit: In your case, it would be DirectoryIndex PHPPage.php

Comment: Good stuff. No need to make CW though - you don't get rep points in that mode.

Comment: This should be flagged  as the **correct answer**. when visiting a  website (doesn't matter locally on on the remote server) you don't want to click on any file to start surfing!

Comment: @halfer, I am sorry but I joined Stack Overflow yesterday so I don't really know what all the buttons mean ^^

Comment: @Whiteclaws: no probs. Read the Help Centre to find out more about things, but otherwise it's just a question of hanging around, answering and learning. The CW mode is useful where you don't want points (e.g. if you know the question is off-topic but you want to help anyway) or you want it to be editable by low-rep users. Otherwise there's no need to use it.

Comment: (Put another way: when borrowing a rocket ship, don't press buttons on the console randomly `:-)`).

Answer (score 0):

In WebMatrix you can decide what you want your default page to be. If you open the site settings one of them is `Manage Default Pages` and has a list of about 7 different page names.

[image: Manage Default Pages]

You can add your own custom named page at the bottom, then you don't have to use the default.php file name to have it automatically run instead of giving you the directory listing.